# Ionic tabs icon not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I can't show my feed tab icon:

> myapp/src/app/tabs/tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
  <ion-icon name="triangle"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
  <ion-icon name="ellipse"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Tab 2</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
  <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Tab 3</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="feed">
   <ion-icon ios="ios-alert" md="md-alert"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Feed</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHlmT.jpg]

But if i try square, ellipse or triangle like the others tabs work:

> myapp/src/app/tabs/tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
  <ion-icon name="triangle"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
  <ion-icon name="ellipse"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Tab 2</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
  <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Tab 3</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="feed">
  <ion-icon name="triangle"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Feed</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHlmT.jpg]

My [github project](https://github.com/thiagomota456/Ionic-para-iniciantes.git)

Comment: all the others are valid icons from https://ionicons.com/ but "ios-alert" is not from there, is it even a ios-icon?

Comment: This is the solution. My problem happened because I was reading the docmentation version 3.

Comment: Please write your comment with a answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in ionic 5 md and ios not working.use this icon

```
 <ion-icon name="alert-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
```

and for future Reference it's official ionic 5 doc here

```
https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-5/
```